# How to prevent the background image from getting blurry

Tags: css, image, background, blurry

I need to know how to get the background image to not be blurry when text is over it in CSS as it spoils the look of my website if it's blurry.

My CSS is:

```
background: #ff0000 url(img/rain.jpg) top center repeat-y; 
background-size: 100%;
```

But when I load it up where there is text that line goes blurry and I don't want it to so how do I do this?

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jmkeighley/59ELc/)

Comment: My code is:
background: #ff0000 url(img/rain.jpg) top center repeat-y;
background-size: 100%;
But when I load it up where there is text that line goes blurry and I don't want it to so how do I do this?

Comment: put the code in question not in comment ...and if  posible give us a live example in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Ok thank you, I thought jsfiddle was only for JavaScript

Comment: @JoshKeighley the code you pasted is nice. But sadly, not relevant. The relevant thing would be to see what is with the text part that is there. By blurry do you mean "get grayish under the text"? It could be that you have a div whose background is not entirely transparent, but say just 50%. You could easily see what is going on, and be also able to correct it using tools like the CSS tools in Firebug...

Comment: Haha worse @RitabrataGautam! I'll set up a JSFiddle!

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmkeighley/59ELc/
See the way it gets blurry behind where the text is?

Comment: Ok, will do right away!

Comment: All done! @RitabrataGautam

Comment: see my answer and the updated fiddle

Comment: How are you all editing my question?!

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I got it by doing:

```
background: transparent;
```

to the `h2` and `p` elements.

Comment: How does transparent background prevent the background image from getting blurry ...

Answer (score 50):

Try to add:

```
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
```

Comment: They should have it inbuilt in the browser with this feature . Why would someone want their images blurred. Duh

Comment: it will look terrible if you are scaling down the image with this answer

Answer (score 12):

Here's the cross browser technique:

```
 image-rendering: crisp-edges;
 image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* Firefox */
 image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            /* Opera */
 image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Webkit (non-standard naming)*/
 -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   /* IE (non-standard property) */
```

Answer (score 11):

Try adding this to the code: `image-rendering: pixelated;` For me it worked perfectly.
you can also try -  `image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `image-rendering: pixelated`. Here is an example from the Mozilla Developer Network:

```
.pixelated {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

https://jsfiddle.net/9dtj2wkq/

Answer (score 5):

use of `background-size: cover;background-position:50% 50%;` will help you..

```
* {
font-family: Calibri, Comic Sans MS, Serif;
background: #ff0000 url(http://www.coolguysite.co.uk/blog/templates/default/img/rain.jpg)   top center repeat-y;
background-size: cover;
background-position:50% 50%;
}
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/59ELc/1/)**