# Text gets blurry when using transform(-50%,-50%) to center the section

Tags: html, css, transform, blur

I use this code to center a section : (This is the only way I can do to center this section )

```
<div class="clock-section">
          <h5 id="clock-title">We are coming really soon</h5>
                <hr class="hr" id="cdhr">
              </div>
```

CSS :

```
.clock-section {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
     transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The section is centered well , but the problem is that the text gets blurry and also the hr looks ugly and blurry,
I have tried all methods like webfont smooth etc, but didn't work at all ! :(
Can anyone help me ?
Thanks ...

Comment: I tested it on Chrome and Firefox, the text does not gets blurry for me...

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411361/webkit-based-blurry-distorted-text-post-animation-via-translate3d

Comment: you can't use margin or something else to center it?

Comment: @AhsN In the case i am using it , its very blurry and ugly , the browser doesn't matters , its blurry in Chrome , Opera and Firefox ...

Comment: @cocoa thanks for the link but it didn't help me at all ! i tasted it but nothing changed ! and as I told i have to use transform ... :)

Comment: can you post image or fiddle? As @Ahs N said, can't find any issue with text or hr.

Comment: @CodeRomeos unfortunately the project is very complicated that is impossible to create fiddle of it ... but about picture , here is the problem when I use transform , the text and hr gets blurry : http://themeliberty.ir/problem1.png ,And when I remove the transform , everything is ok and the text is nice : http://themeliberty.ir/problem2.png

Comment: ah, there's a background image. that would have been good to know

Answer (score 1):

From a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677983/how-to-prevent-the-background-image-from-getting-blurry), the answer was

```
h5 {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Not sure if that is the answer in your case.

EDIT: 
Or how about this?

```
.parent-element {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Comment: darn. wish i could see the blurriness on my side

Comment: how about using pixel values instead of percentages for the transform?

Comment: I am using transform(-50%) to center the section which has unknown height and width , How can I use pixel value to center the section ? is there a way ?

Comment: i don't know how to do it unless the parent has a defined height and width.

Comment: you know , I cant share the project in public , can you give me an email address or something so that I can send you the files ? Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: sure, i don't know if i'll be able to help much more though. i've just been googling. my email is in my profile

Comment: Thanks anyway , i appreciate your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all of solutions, sometimes they worked sometimes didn't. Finally I gave up to use this method to center elements. Instead of using transform try this :

```
width: 50vw;
height:50vh;
position: fixed;/*or absolute*/
margin:25vh 25vw;
```

This code centers the main element on screen. You can use flex or another solution to center inside elements...